# Making XNA Play Nice With 3DS Max, Boundiing Spheres

Tags: xna-4.0, models, 3dsmax, culling, fbx

I'm using 3DS Max 2010 with the KW x-porter plugin, which outputs a .X file (just downloaded the very latest version).

Been getting some odd results:
http://www.picvalley.net/u/2930/2265240220441812321333990933PAStFeSONWQslOrMQC5q.PNG

Looks like the culling is screwed up.  Note, that models I make in Milkshape don't seem to be having these problems.

I've also tried to export an FBX file from 3DS Max 2010 and have been getting similar results.

What are your suggestions in terms of exporting *.3DS models to a workable XNA form?  What tools do you use?.

To be clear, the model in question has none of these defects when viewed from similar angles in 3DS Max 2010.

http://www.picvalley.net/u/2563/151728957814855401111333991302mSvEJ03Zv22GwHFgIhiV.PNG

Any ideas on this oddity would also be appreciated!

**Edit 1 -- Add'l issue**
Forgot to mention, that the model otherwise seems alright, but that rotation seems to double -- in other words, when I scroll my camera view left to right, the model (whose draw I give the camera for the view and perspective matrices w/ BasicEffect seems to rotate twice as much as models I draw natively in XNA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have depth testing enabled. Put this code before drawing your model:

```
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

Comment: Great, that worked!

Only problem is I think I need to reset it after to preserve my Milkshape models, as they're now messed up...
http://www.picvalley.net/u/1919/120561781712716419013339927623gBpGPJAqTJRmfoQ26e0.PNG

That also seemed to fix the rotation issue, fyi!

Comment: Did you get my followup question?  How do I reset the DepthStencilState to its previous value?

Comment: Save it and then re-set it.

DepthStencilState oldState = GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
// Your rendering
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = oldState;